# Toggle slide out div with jQuery & push div onto new line

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a small issue with a project i'm working on.

It's probably very simple but I'm not overly proficient with jquery and am having a few issues. I basically want to have a grid of 4 item rows, once a user clicks on a div, it slides out a bio the same width as the grid item (25%). Then pushes the div beside it onto a new row.

To give an idea, it's for an "our team" page, this page will display the photo of everyone in the grid and if they click the person it slides out their bio.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="team-list one-fourth nomargin">
     <div class="team-photo">
         <img class="front" src="{front_image}" alt="{title}" />
     </div>
     <div class="team-bio">
         team bio here
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* THE TEAM PAGE */
.team-list {
    position:relative;
}

.team-list .team-photo img {
    max-width:100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7bJML/

Many thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood you are looking something like this. I hope it will help

Add this handler for sliding bio info:

```
$('.team-photo').click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

And CSS:

```
/* THE TEAM PAGE */
.team-list {
    position:relative;
    cursor: pointer
}

.team-list .team-photo img {
    max-width:100%;
}

.team-bio {
    display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QrfzA/

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. Seems to be the correct concept I'm trying to achieve. Although I need the div to slide out right and be the same width as the image (25% - 4 row grid).

Comment: Hi Trim, thanks again. Sort of, this is more along the lines of what I need however, the only issue being... I need the bio to be hidden first, then only appear on clicked. Also, I need it to push the div over 25% when the bio is slid out. http://jsfiddle.net/QrfzA/17/

Comment: The issue seems to be the absolute positioning, it's not going to push any of the divs right if I use absolute positioning for the bio... Any other suggestions?

Comment: I've edited the jsfiddle. I managed to hide the div and have it appear onclick but it takes two clicks before it works? If I can fix the show and hide of the div's it's not 100% nessesary that it pushes the grid onto a new line. I don't mind if it just overlaps as it currently does. Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/QrfzA/19/

Comment: Hi kala233, as much as I understood with my moderate English. Here is an updated jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jareck/QrfzA/20/